# CMake Error with OpenSSL

Tags: cmake

I'm having an issue with CMake not recognizing my OpenSSL files. Below I've included the error being shown and a picture to the OPENSSL directories on the CMake side.

Using Windows 10, CMake 3.11.1, OpenSSL - Win64 v1.1.0.

```
CMake Error at D:/Private Server/Cmake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Private Server/Cmake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  src/cmake/macros/FindOpenSSL.cmake:175 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:70 (find_package)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvpPZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't wrote how are you looking for OpenSSL package. I see on the screenshot that OpenSSL is installed in non-standard path.
The find module documentation recommend to setup [OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindOpenSSL.html) cmake variable (before you trigger find_package).

Another problem could be you are in 32-bit build environment and cmake try to search for libs in libraries with 32 arch suffix.